# почему не срабатывает clearTimeout?

Tags: javascript

```js
function printNumbersInterval(){
  var d = 1;
var s = setTimeout(function f(){
  if (d > 20){
    clearTimeout(s);
  }
   console.log(d++);
  s = setTimeout(f, 100)
}, 100)

};

console.log( printNumbersInterval() );
```

Comment: p.s. а вы знали про setInterval ?

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME да  знал,  а Вы знали что рекурсивный setTimeout надежнее ?

Comment: @user345125 интересно чем

Comment: Stranger, просто это человек из секты рекурсивных разработчиков, один раз узнали про это, теперь сломя голову постоянно используют это даже там, где это попросту не нужно.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ `setTimeout` в некоторых случаях действительно предпочтительней. Представьте. что выполняете относительно долгую асинхронную операцию. В случае с  `setTimeout` у вас будут равные интервалы запуска.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko  это не показатель надежности, тайминги между вызовами разные - это да, они просто для разных случаев

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я и не говорил про надежность :-) Я говорил, что в некоторых случаях `setTimeout` предпочтительнее. А вообще интересно, что значит "надежность" в данном случае.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko вот и я не понял как тут она аказалась и куда ее приложить

Comment: @user345125 что значит, что `setTimeout` надежнее? Что вы подразумеваете под словом "надежность" в данном контексте?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko хотя вот при обсчетах состояний в физическом движке, более точный результат дает именно фиксированный интервал между началом выполнения функции

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну это логично. Мы же не хотим, что бы результат зависел от мощности видеокарты.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko да, срезы времени нужны с фиксированной периодичностью, иначе необходимы дополнительные вычисления, стобы компенсировать это еще одной интерполяцией

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: @user345125 Вы почитайте нашу переписку со Степаном, это ни имеет никакого отношения к НАДЕЖНОСТИ

Comment: @Stranger in the Q лучше когда промежутки точно соблюдаются как в рекурсивном setTimeout чем в setInterval

Comment: @user345125 нет не лучше, это просто другое поведение, для некоторых ситуаций как раз лучше делать проверки через фиксированные интервалы времени и не полагаться на то с какой скоростью отработает слушатель

Comment: @Stranger in the Q ясно, но вопрос был как использовать clearTimeout в рекурсивном setTimeout, а Вы свой ответ не показали :((

Comment: @user345125 либо вам на вопрос уже ответили, либо я не понимаю в чем он заключается

Comment: `(f = () => console.log(this.d = this.d + 1 || 1) || this.d < 20 && setTimeout(f, 100))()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это связано с тем, что после очистки `setTimeout`, код идет выполняться ниже, а у вас там присваивание нового `setTimeout`.

Что бы этого избежать, у вас есть 2 выхода:

1. После очистки `setTimeout` ниже написать `return`, что бы функция прекратила свое выполнение на этом месте.
2. Или же по другому сделать условия через `if`, `else`.

Ниже в коде я оставил комментарии.

P.S: **Stepan Kasyanenko** в ответе правильно написал, что можно обойти и без очистки `setTimeout`.

```js
function printNumbersInterval() {
  var d = 1;
  var s = setTimeout(function f() {
    if (d > 20) {
      clearTimeout(s);
      return; //Все что ниже не будет выполнено.
    }
    console.log(d++);
    s = setTimeout(f, 100)
  }, 100)

};

//или сделать условия if, else

//if (d > 20) {
//  clearTimeout(s);
//} else {
//  console.log(d++);
//  s = setTimeout(f, 100)
//}

console.log(printNumbersInterval());
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам здесь `clearTimeout` не нужен. Просто не запускайте следующий `setTimeout`, если он не нужен.

```js
function printNumbersInterval() {
  var d = 1;
  setTimeout(function f() {
    if (d > 20) {
      return; // выходим из функции, не запуская еще раз setTimeout
    }
    console.log(d++);
    setTimeout(f, 100);
  }, 100)

};

console.log(printNumbersInterval());
```